# Regex validation with @Pattern annotation in spring data

Tags: java, regex, spring-data, constraints

I need password validation (for example a password must contain at least 4 chars, max 8 and min 1 numeric digit).
I have model (of course with getters and setters):

```
   @Entity
public class User implements Serializable{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5534441879591858724L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*\\d).{4,8}$", flags = Flag.UNICODE_CASE)
    private String password;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String name;
```

I'm catching ConstraintViolationException during saving user info to database and use informations from this exception to inform the user during registration what fields must be corrected because of invalid length etc.

Everything is ok with validation, but not with password. I checked regex expression out of this model class and it works ok, but when i put this regex  into annotation parameter ( `@Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*\\d).{4,8}$", flags = Flag.UNICODE_CASE)`) it doesn't work and I have an error:

> HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Validation failed for classes
>   [pl.rpf.kingdom.models.User] during persist time for groups
>   [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint violations:[
>           ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must match "^(?=.*\d).{4,8}$"', propertyPath=password, rootBeanClass=class
>   pl.rpf.kingdom.models.User,
>   messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message}'} ]]

Please help me with understanding this error and maybe you have some idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: You may benefit from reading [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/). I'm not sure why you're capping passwords between 4 and 8 characters...

Comment: Which password failed the check?

Comment: Ok. It's only example, regex is not so important now. If it will works with one correct regex i will find better regex for stronger password ;)

Comment: actualy p.ex pass123 will not work too (it has at least 4, max 8 chars, one number). But I tested it in other class with normal matches() method and it was ok. Only with my annotation it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with password encrypting, I forgot about it. 
Regex matches mathod was always false, because it was trying to compare password after encrypting. 
I solved problem by putting validation out of model class, before password encrypting. 
Other way to resolve problem could be using spring `@Valid` annotation to validate form before trying save it to database (in my situation it could be problematic from other cases).

Comment: The passwords should be hashed not encrypted.